# Filtering Dataframe by keeping numeric values of a specific column only in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset, data-manipulation

I've the following dataframe

| Group | Cost | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21 | 2017 |
| A | 22 | 2016 |
| A | closed | 2015 |
| B | 12 | 2017 |
| B | 11 | 2016 |
| C | ended | 2017 |
| C | closing | 2016 |
| C | 13 | 2015 |

```
Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
Cost = c(21,22,"closed", 12, 11,"ended", "closing", 13)
Year = c(2017,2016,2015,2017,2016,2017,2016,2015)
df = data.frame(Group, Cost, Year)
```

Anybody knows how I can filter the dataframe (df) based on keeping over the numeric values in the Cost column? The outcome should be the following table

| Group | Cost | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21 | 2017 |
| A | 22 | 2016 |
| B | 12 | 2017 |
| B | 11 | 2016 |
| C | 13 | 2015 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `df %>%  filter(!is.na(as.numeric(Cost)))` using `library(dplyr)`

Comment: tried this method initially but it still kept the text entries in the cost column

Comment: Well, with `df` made by your code provided, it might works. Does your `df` different with that?

Comment: I think the challenge here is that R recognises all the entry under Cost as characters or numeric (for both text and number), thus the filter(!is.na(as.numeric))) part might not work

Comment: Yes, what I suppose is `Cost` columns is `character`.

Comment: @Luther_Proton could you please share the ouput of `str(df)` with `df` being your "real" dataframe? My hypothesis is that, if the `Cost` colum is factor (very possible if you used `read.csv(..., stringAsFactors = TRUE)` for ex), then, the usual filtering techniques presented here do not work as they do for `character` class colums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to filter the relevant rows of your dataframe.
The regular expression `^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$` will check for character that contains only digits, possibly with `.` as a decimal separator (*i.e.* 2, 2.3). You could then convert the `Cost` column to numeric using `as.numeric()` if needed.

See the example below:

```r
Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")
Cost = c(21,22,"closed", 12, 11,"ended", "closing", 13)
Year = c(2017,2016,2015,2017,2016,2017,2016,2015)
df = data.frame(Group, Cost, Year)


df[grep(pattern = "^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$", df[,"Cost"]), ]
#>   Group Cost Year
#> 1     A   21 2017
#> 2     A   22 2016
#> 4     B   12 2017
#> 5     B   11 2016
#> 8     C   13 2015
```

Note that this technique works even if your `Cost` column is of `factor` class while using `df[!is.na(as.numeric(df$Cost)), ]` does not. For the latter you need to add `as.character()` first: `df[!is.na(as.numeric(as.character(df$Cost))), ]`. Both techniques keep factor levels.